# Timer Trigger Azure Function not getting trigger on next day

Tags: azure-functions

Timer trigger azure function with "TimerConfig": "0 */30 * * * *" is getting triggered for every 30 minutes only on the day of deployment but from very next day is not getting triggered on schedule ie every 30 minutes. Any  suggestions or different type of schedule available? please.

Note: we are deploying azure function to function app using octupus deploy & timer configuration are set by octopus variable. After deployment "TimerConfig:" values are verified & it is set as expected.

Comment: How is this `TimerConfig` setting read? How is it applied to the Function? What does the actual Function's code look like?

Comment: How are you deploying your functions?

Comment: What's your service plan? Did you enable Always On?

Comment: For this to work, your triggers need to be 'synced'. Try click the little Refresh icon next to your Function App name in the Portal and see if it helps. If still an issue , share your function app name by following https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, your triggers need to be 'synced'. Try click the little Refresh icon next to your Function App name in the Portal and see if it helps. If still an issue , share your function app name by following the below link with date and time in UTC .

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately